# How to circle a part of an image? How to edit an image?

Tags: google-docs

I have an image included in a Google Docs doc.  I would like to circle part of the image in yellow.

1. is there a native way to edit an image directly in Google Docs?
2. if not, what is the best way to go about this?  perhaps save image (how?), edit outside, re-import?  It seems really fiddly doing this manually but I wondered if anyone has a nice pattern / sequence to enable this.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Google Drawings**, it's integrated in Google Docs.

If your image is already inserted in the document,

1. Cut the image.
2. Click **Insert** > **Drawing** > **+ New**.
3. Paste the image in the Google Drawings canvas.
4. Use the tools in Google Drawings to make the desired changes.
5. Click the **Save and Close** button.